# Adding Email to my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I currently Have an application that can sign up a subscriber. Everything is pretty basic at this point. The people I'm creating this app for would like the ability to send custom emails to everybody that is subscribed. I'm new to web development and I'm not sure what the capabilities of rails are and I'm not sure what the best way to handle this request is? My first thought is to try and integrate with the mailchimp api and when a user subscribes it automatically fills their email and name in the mailchimp list. So, now the owners of the app can send custom email through mailchimp. My question is - What is the best way to implement this feature in my rails app. What services are available and what tutorials will help me set it up? Any help would be great Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pragmatic studio has a decent tutorial on how to set up ActionMailer. I would recommend watching it and then moving on to third-party tools for production.

[How to Create, Preview, and Send email from your Rails app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eFXEzOPRNs)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the gem I used to send emails from my rails app. https://github.com/mikel/mail . This gem has good documentation and I am sure you can handle your requirements using this.